# Many to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I'm trying to build an application on Laravel 5.3 where my models, database and controllers are in separate folders. I have the following folder structure:

```
Nitseditor
    System
        Controllers
        Database
            2016_12_28_130149_create_domains_table.php
            2017_01_06_193355_create_themes_table.php
            2017_01_07_140804_create_themes_domains_table.php
        Models
            Domain.php
            Theme.php
```

I'm making a relationship in domain with many to many relationship i.e.

```
public function themes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Nitseditor\System\Models\Domain');
}
```

I've named the table `domain_theme` inside the `2017_01_07_140804_create_themes_domains_table.php`

Now I'm trying to get the theme name which belongs to the domain in the controller something like this:

```
$flashmesage = new Domain;

foreach ($flashmesage->themes as $theme)
{
    return $theme->theme_name;
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'nitswebbuilder.domain_domain' doesn't exist (SQL: select `domains`.*, `domain_domain`.`domain_id` as `pivot_domain_id` from `domains` inner join `domain_domain` on `domains`.`id` = `domain_domain`.`domain_id` where `domain_domain`.`domain_id` is null and `domains`.`deleted_at` is null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for my short comment as answer... I have not enough reputation for comment,

change your `themes()` method to :

```
public function themes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Nitseditor\System\Models\Theme');
}
```

see [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many) for more info

Comment: Silly mistake. Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Table name should be called `domain_theme`. If you've used corrent names for foreign keys and have built correct relationships, [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) will work for you:

```
$domainName = 'example.com';

$themes = Theme::whereHas('domains', function($q) ($domainName) {
    $q->where('domain_name', $domainName);
})->get();
```

Then show all themes names:

```
@foreach ($themes as $theme)
    {{ $theme->theme_name }}
@endforeach
```